# Finding optimal path (if exists)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, computer-science

Given the parameter *k* and an array *[a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>]*, where *a<sub>x</sub>* defines the height of the terrain, find the least amount of work you need to make the terrain passable. The terrain is passable that if the difference between two neighbouring places is smaller or equal to *k*. The height of the terrain at *a<sub>x</sub>* can be changed and the amount of work needed is equal to the difference in height you make. The height of *a<sub>0</sub>* and a<sub>n</sub> can't be changed and therefore some terrains may be completely unpassable.

I've been struggling with this for a while: This is what I figured out so far: Of course finding a solution (not taking the least amount of work needed into account) is easy - make 'steps' from *a<sub>0</sub>* to *a<sub>n</sub>* as in the diagram with k = 2 (red dots are the heights of the old terrain, grey for the new).

[image: diagram 1 - unoptimal]

(The input for this particular terrain would be: k = 2, [0, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 7])

As you can see, the new terrain doesn't take the old terrain into account and thus the work needed to transform the old one into this one can be huge.

Determining whether a path exists is trivial: k >= |a<sub>0</sub>-a<sub>n</sub>|/n, but I have no idea about how would I go around in finding the optimal solution.

Comment: what is the expected time and space complexity?

Comment: Time and space complexity wasn't considered, but brute force is surely not the right way to go.

Comment: then you can surely make brute force using bfs

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: What are the range of values that a_i's, n and k can take?

Comment: 0 <= a_i <= 10^9, 2 <= n <= 200, k <= 10^9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the simplex method to solve the following linear program.

```
minimize sum_i y_i
subject to
# y_i is notionally |x_i - a_i|
# equality holds in every optimal solution
y_i >= x_i - a_i for all i
y_i >= a_i - x_i for all i
# transformed terrain is passable, i.e., |x_i - x_{i+1}| <= k
x_i - x_{i+1} <= k for all i
x_{i+1} - x_i <= k for all i
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how would you apply this?

Comment: @FigsHigs There's a lot of free online tutorial material on linear programming and the simplex method in particular.

Comment: Ok. I'll try and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

One brute force solution is like this
For each element consider three next states, one with h + 1, h + 0, h - 1 where h is height of element. Now keep on traversing the array and see the following points
1)If the state has been arrived earlier discard it( so make bitmask dp for that )

2)If the you arrive at a state where traversed adjacent element diff is not k discard it.

3)If total work done till now is more than the minimum till found discard it.

Comment: this is just the idea, i will posting the code and better algo( if possible ) sooner

Comment: This could grow to a very large tree very soon. Consider a terrain with 150 places (indexes) and very large and different heights.

Comment: i agree thats why it is brute force :), i am thinking about other approach , will let you know

Comment: also there is a point if height of first element is h, second element can be in [h-k,h+k] so number of possible states is 2k, also this is valid for last element so keep on traversing from front and back sides simultaneosly this will prevent somehow in expanding the tree

Comment: That's true, but this deals with any path, not optimal path.

Comment: it will be optimal only , we are only consider valid cases, not discarding any potential solution, we are exploring all possible and valid solutions and storing the value if < already min found, so in this way we are discarding many braches to go further

Answer (score 0):

Let be ht = an-a0 the total height. Let hAverageStep = ht/n. And k is the maximum step.

Ideally, at step 'i' the difference of height should be i*hAverageStep. In this case the path is just a constant straight. We want to get closer to this straight.

For the step 'i' you can observe if you need some "work" in this point to move it to the straight. If that work is greater than k, you must move also other points, for example some previous you have not worked enough.

If after moving every point as much as needed still 'an' is not reached, there's no solution.